# Unexpected character "

Tags: c#, selenium

For some reason I am getting an error message `Unexpected character "` however it doesn't actually underline any of my code in read. I tried cleaning and rebuilding it but that hasn't worked. It says it's on line 49.

My code is as follows

```
By maximizeBy = By.Name("Maximize");
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(maximiz‌​eBy));
```

Line 49 below

```
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(‌​
    excelSession.FindEle‌​ment(maximizeBy))).Cl‌​ick();
```

Comment: Do you have anything in the Output window?

Comment: In C# you get rather an exception, what is the exact type and message of the exception being rised?

Comment: Which line is line 49?

Comment: It's a compile time error so I can't run my program . In the error List I just get  `Unexpected Character "`

Comment: @JonSkeet it's the `webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(‌​
    excelSession.FindEle‌​ment(maximizeBy))).Cl‌​ick();` line

Comment: Can you reproduce this as a [mcve]? (All you're trying to do is reproduce the error. The code doesn't need to do anything useful.)

Comment: (I was considering closing this as a typo, but I can see how the same error message could be useful for others.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it also may be useful for others but I do see your point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got two "odd" characters within `FindElement` - [U+200C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200C/index.htm) (zero-width non-joiner) and [U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) (zero-width space) between the first "e" and the "m". The same characters occur in "Click" between the "l" and the "i".

Just delete and retype those words and the error should go away. It's not clear how you ended up with those characters, admittedly...

Comment: This worked however I had to re-type the whole line. Thanks very much for your answer. Such a stupid error

Comment: @CraigGallagher: I see there's the same problem in `Click` (I'll update my answer) but those should be the only two places.

Comment: Did you by any chance copy your code from Microsoft documentation? I heard a colleague talking about Microsoft using those zero-width spaces in their documentation, driving them crazy as well :>

Comment: I'm impressed that the SO syntax highlighting picks up the issue! (e.g. only half the word is coloured)

Comment: I'm doing my usual trolling of the [selenium] tag and I notice this question had an answer with 7 upvotes?!? ... in less than a day!?! Then I scroll down... Jon Skeet... figures... lol.